# On the operator norm of a linear function in finite dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Consider a linear functional $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$. We can consider the operator norm
$$
|| f ||_B = \max\{|f(x_1,\dots,x_n)| : ||(x_1,\dots,x_n)|| \leq 1\}
$$

where $||\cdot||$ is any norm in $\mathbb{R}^n$. I was playing with the classical norms in $\mathbb{R}^n$, including $||\cdot||_1$ and $||\cdot||_{\infty}$. My claim is that the maximum of $|f(x_1,\dots,x_n)|$ is attained at the corners of the respective balls. Visually, is quite clear in $\mathbb{R}^2$, where $f(x,y) = ax+by$ defines a plane and where the unit balls in $||\cdot||_1$ and $||\cdot||_{\infty}$ are, respectively, a diamond and a square. But I'd like to formally prove a general version of this observation. 'The corners' would translate more formally as 'the points of the boundary whose euclidean distance to the origin is maximal'. Can you help me? I'd like a proof that uses multivariate analysis, not a theorem that requires knowing an entire advanced branch of maths.

Comment: Look up the definition of face of a convex set.  On a compact convex set, a linear functional attains its maximum on a face.  Similarly for minimum.

Comment: @ChadK Thanks for answering, I looked it up and seems quite interesting, but it seems that there should be a simple proof in finite dimension. I'd like to have a proof that does not involved more than real/multivariate analysis, linear algebra and basic topology.

Comment: absolute value of a linear function is a convex function, and the maximum of a convex function on a compact set is always attained on the boundary

Comment: @Exodd thanks for answering, but how can I prove this with my hypotheses? I'd like to write a proof using multivariate analysis, not a result of a more advanced branch of mathematics.

Comment: more easily, $f(\lambda x) = \lambda f(x)$, so the maximum is necessarily attained for the biggest $|\lambda|$ possible

Comment: @Exodd that proves that the maximum over the segment with extreme points $x$ and the origin is attained at $x$.  How do you prove that $|f(x)|>|f(y)||$ if the euclidean distancie of $x$ to the origin is greatest than the euclidean distance of $y$ to the origin, without $x,y$ lying in the same line.

Comment: notice that $\lambda$ can also be greater than one... the idea is that for every nonzero $x$ there is a real $\lambda$ such that $\lambda x$ is on the boundary

Comment: Yeah, but the problem is comparing points in the boundary. My conjecture says that the maximum is attained at the corners, not at a generic point in the boundary.

Comment: ok, sorry, I thought you were considering also euclidean norm. But in general it's true by practically the same reasoning and induction: the maximum is at the boundary, so take the face on the boundary you're in and restrict the function to that face. It is still a linear function (up to a proper choice of the new origin on the hyperplane), so you can repeat the reasoning and find that the maximum is on the boundary of the face, and repeat again until you converge to a corner